# If someone with no exposure to the Bible / Christianity were to spend 1hr reading the Bible, what passage(s) would you point them to?

Tags: evangelism, christianity-in-india

In this case, these will be young professionals in India who've never read the Bible and have very little exposure to Christianity. Really appreciate your suggestions! (feel free to also suggest what you'd recommend if they were read a 2nd hr as a followup)

EDIT: if this is not the right forum for this question, but you know where I should ask instead, please feel free to DM me or comment.

Comment: Welcome to Christianity SE and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1809/50259).

Comment: Is the main goal to get them interested in further reading, or to explain the basics of Christianity?  The answers would be very different.

Answer (score 4):

I have a friend who starts bible reading plans with young folk in treatment centers who have no biblical exposure and he takes them through Proverbs first.  This is because he is then able to help them make direct links between their poor choices and their difficult circumstances.  From there he takes them into the gospels to lead them to the solution in Christ.  Although those in active addiction and young professionals may not seem to have much in common, there may be a similar emptiness which, resulting from worldly choices, Proverbs may speak toward.  Obviously this is more than a one time, one hour reading schedule.

If a one time, one hour read is the aim I would suggest the Gospel of John.  This Gospel can be read in an hour by most people and the stated purpose of this Gospel is:

> And many other signs truly did Jesus in the presence of his disciples, which are not written in this book: But these are written, that ye might believe that Jesus is the Christ, the Son of God; and that believing ye might have life through his name. - John 20:30-31

Obviously, anyone with no bible exposure will come away from a reading of the gospel of John with many questions and the hope is that those questions may be engaged but it is not always the case.  God's word is able to pierce the darkness regardless. The [Pocket Testament League](https://www.ptl.org/about/our-history/) has been handing out small booklets containing the gospel of John for over a hundred years.

Over and above these suggestions, a godly person intimate with the Bible and the mindset and culture of young Indian professionals may prayerfully be led to an entirely different starting place.  All of Scripture is God-breathed and profitable.

Comment: When I became a believer, John was the first book that engaged me. Two years later, I embarked on a yearlong study of the Wisdom Books, spending the first six months on Proverbs alone. Between the two, I had solid answer to two important questions: (1) What specifically is wrong with how I am leading my life? (2) To whom can I turn for help? So based on personal experience, I can endorse these two books as a good starting point.

Comment: The opening verses in John's gospel had a profound effect on my view of Christianity.  John grabs your attention, basically says, "Listen up, this is important" and then, without any preamble or literary politeness, tells you exactly who Jesus Christ REALLY is.  I love John's gospel!  Start there and then the rest falls into place.